# How to mock FastAPI Request

Tags: python, mocking, fastapi, web-api-testing

I'm trying to test a FastAPI endpoint but I'm getting the fllowing eroor

```
AttributeError: 'State' object has no attribute 'session'
```

Whern the test endpoint is triggered, it is creating an object of the associated function and the original method is being invoked, not the mocked one!

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app 

test_client = TestClient(app)

@patch('mymodule.get_session_information')
def test(mock_get_session_information):
    mock_session_info = SessionInformationResult(
        session_handle=SessionInformationResult.SessionHandle({"username_bool": True}),
        user_id="test_user_id",
        session_data={},
        expiry=81,
        access_token_payload={"username_bool": True},
        time_created=637,
    )
    mock_get_session_information.return_value = mock_session_info
    response = test_client.get("/isunthere")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == True
```

I tried creating a mock session but it's not getting triggered.

Comment: Please don't spam user notifications. People will see your question when they have time, opportunity and knowledge. Please include a minimum example of the _code you're trying to mock_ that shows the issue; this seems related to the `state` object in FastAPI's request; you'd generally use a dependency override to handle it, but it's impossible to say without you including the code that fails.